# Pivot.SelectedIndex corrupts Pivot Header

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, windows-phone-8.1, pivotitem

I am writing a Windows Phone 8.1 App (WINRT)

I have a Pivot with 3 pivot items in page.

When page loads i have set Pivot.SelectedIndex=2. So, when page opens, it goes to third pivot item but the header of pivot remains of first item. When tapping the pivot manually, header gets updated.

What is the problem?

Comment: Where do you put the line `Pivot.SelectedIndex=2` - in constructor or other event?

Comment: Please show your code..

Comment: @Romasz I was loading it in this.Loaded method, but i shifted it to constructor and its working fine.